# Is c++11 range-for not equal to classic for in terms of functionality?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

One would expect them to work exactly the same way, but .

```
class Range
{
public:
    class DontMindMe
    {
    public:
        DontMindMe(int a) : a_(a) {}
        bool operator ==(const DontMindMe& ot) {return a_ == ot.a_;}
        bool operator !=(const DontMindMe& ot) {return !(*this==ot);}
        int operator *(void) {return a_;}
        DontMindMe& operator++() {++a_; return *this;}
        DontMindMe  operator++(int) {auto temp{*this}; ++a_; return temp;}
    private:
        int a_;
    };

    Range(int a, int b, const std::string& msg)
        : a_(a), b_(b) {std::cout << msg << std::endl;}
    DontMindMe begin() {return a_;}
    DontMindMe end() {return b_;}
private:
    int a_;
    int b_;
};

int main()
{
    for(auto it = Range::DontMindMe(1); it != Range(1,10, "C++").end(); ++it);

    std::cout << std::endl;

    for(auto it : Range(1,10, "C++11")); 
}
```

First loop prints the message 10 times, second one prints it only once. Are they not equal? Can this difference complicate old code revision?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> First loop prints the message 10 times, second one prints it only once.

That's right, because in the first loop you've asked the compiler to create a new `Range` to compare the iterator to each time you enter the loop.

> Are they not equal?

No

> Can this difference complicate old code revision?

Not usually. It's just that you've created a contrived example.

Comment: The practice of recalculating the end of range on every loop iteration is frowned upon - and rightfully so.